# iScroll v4.2.5 - scroll not working after 'back'

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I have the following code

```
  <div id="mission_content" style="padding: 10px; margin:0; padding-bottom: 37px;" data-iscroll="scroller">
    <div data-bind="html: info.text"></div>
  </div>
```

I'm using iScroll v4.2.5 (http://cubiq.org) and it works great (JQM, phonegap, Knockout)

but when I do back and then go into the page again the iscroll is not applied and I cannot scroll the content at all.

When I remove the `data-iscroll="scroller"` the scroll is working but there is no scrollbar.

Any idea of a quick solution?

Answer (score 0):

this is actually caused by the JQM/Knockout - u should never bind/initialise object twice, i.e. always do this:

```
    this.isInit = false;

    this.initialize = function(challenge) {
        if (this.isInit) return;
        this.isInit = true;
```